# hover() function not working properly

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery function that displays a pop-up menu when the div is hovered over:

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
    $('.thumbnail').hover(function (e) {
        $(this).children('.pop-up').show()
            .css('top', e.pageY + 20)
            .css('left', e.pageX + 10)
            .appendTo('body');
    }, function () {
        $(this).children('.pop-up').hide();
    });
</script>
```

The first function works well (the pop-up menu is displayed when the cursor is hover the div) but the second is not (the hide function)

Any ideas? Thank you

**Edit**

Here is my HTML Structure :

```
    <div class="thumbnail">
                            .........
<div class='pop-up'><h3>"@thumbnail.Forfait.Titre"</h3><p>"@thumbnail.Forfait.Description"</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post your HTML structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you have appended the `.pop-up` elements to the body, so they are no longer children of the `.thumbnail` element.

Change the code in the second function to this and it should work:

```
$('body').children('.pop-up').hide().appendTo(this);
```

This assumes there are no other elements with a class of `.pop-up`

Edit - As mentioned by cfs in the comments. It is a good idea to re-append the pop-up to the thumbnail so it will still work on next hover.

Comment: You should probably re-append this popup to the thumbnail after it is hidden, or else the it won't show after the first time you hover of a thumbnail

Comment: May be I should append it to the thumbnail and not to the body element :) no ?

Comment: Thanks. Updated the answer to include that.

Answer (score 1):

When you append the `.pop-up` to the `body`, it is no longer a child of the `.thumbnail` div, it is a child of the `body`, so

```
$(this).children('.pop-up').hide();
```

doesn't work.

Why are you appending to the body in the first place? It doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: Shall I append the pop-up in the thumbnail ? I think that I can't because there is many thumbnails (there a loop with many thumbnails that have the same class)

Comment: Why do you feel that you need to change what it's appended to at all? Have you tried removing the `.appendTo('body');` part?

Comment: No I should append to body, but now everything works fine :) Thank you all Guys :) I just put $('body').children('.pop-up').hide().appendTo(this); like suggested by @Richard Dalton and it works :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, the `.pop-up` elements you select in the first handler are appended to the `body` element.

On the other handler, `$(this).children('.pop-up')` simply does not return any element anymore because they are not children anymore.

Comment: Shall I append the pop-up in the thumbnail ? I think that I can't because there is many thumbnails (there a loop with many thumbnails that have the same class)